# What is the difference between seeding a action and call a 'setter' method of a store in reflux data flow?

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

What is the difference between seeding a action and call a 'setter' method of a store in reflux data flow?

```
TodoActions['add'](todo)
```

vs

```
TodoStore.add(todo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Action will trigger your store via RefluxJS lib, but Store.Add() is calling add method directly

Comment: So what is the point to use Action? Why not just call the method?

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's useful to note that `Whatever.func()` and `Whatever['func']()` are just two different syntaxes for the same thing. So the only difference here in your example is what you're calling it on.

As far as calling a method in a store directly, vs. an action which then ends up calling that method in a store, the difference is architectural, and has to do with following a pattern that is more easily scaled, works more broadly, etc. etc.

If any given event within the program (such as, in this case, adding something) emits 1 clear action that anything can listen for, then it becomes MUCH easier to build large programs, edit previously made programs, etc. The component saying that this event has happened doesn't need to keep track of everywhere that might need to know about it...it just needs to say `TodoActions.add(todo)`, and every other part of the program that needs to know about an addition happening can manage itself to make sure it's listening for that action.

So that's why we follow the 1 way looping pattern:

`component -> action -> store -> back to component`

Because then the flow of events happening is much more easily managed, because each part of the program can manage its own knowledge about the program state and when it needs to be changed. The component emitting the action doesn't need to know every possible part of the program that might need that action...it just needs to emit it.